# Update chart with vba , adding years to series

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to update chart type 4 using excel VBA.
I am able to refresh the data source area , but am struggling to show the year fields in a series. and just having Jan , Feb , Mar , Apr , May , Jun , Jul , Aug , Sep , Oct , Nov , Dec as horizontal data.

My data is in 3 columns

```
Year    Month   Total
2018    Jan 0
2018    Feb 2067
2018    Mar 2507
2018    Apr 3319
2018    May 12536
2018    Jun 2108
2018    Jul 1060
2018    Aug 2440
2018    Sep 1423
2018    Oct 939
2018    Nov 2443
2018    Dec 891
2019    Jan 1678
2019    Feb 1715
2019    Mar 1426
2019    Apr 3271
2019    May 1267
2019    Jun 1188
2019    Jul 3603
2019    Aug 1664
```

and is updated each month. I would like to be able to have a chart with Jan to Dec on the horizontal axis . Is there also a way to add an additional year to the series , if when we get to 2020 , there would another year to add.
At present my code , displays `JAN 2018` , `FEB 2018` , etc then `JAN 2019` , `FEB 2019` etc. and the series has Series1 and Year. not 2018 and 2019

I had manually put in years 2018 and 2019 in column K to see if my code would work for series.

```
Option Explicit

Sub UpdateChart()

Dim i As Integer
Dim lw As Long
Dim lrow, daterow As Long

lrow = Sheet8.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
daterow = Sheet8.Cells(Rows.Count, 11).End(xlUp).Row
Sheet8.ChartObjects("Chart1").Activate

ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Sheet8.Range("A2:C" & lrow)
With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
  .Name = "Year"
  .Values = Sheet8.Range("K5:K" & daterow).Value2
End With

ActiveChart.Refresh

End Sub
```

Comment: Create a "helper" column and combine the month and year into a date field that Excel recognizes. A formula such as `=DATEVALUE(B2&" "&A2)` would work (make sure the cell with the formula is formatted to display a date!).  Then use that new date column as the axis in your chart.

Comment: how would I adapt my VBA code to work with this method please

Comment: I'm unclear on what your chart looks like and what exactly you want to accomplish. You want a line chart showing the 12 months on the X axis and a different series for each year of data? Are you creating the chart using VBA or creating the chart manually?